# PHP/MYSQL: showing data out of 2 tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

This is my first question and I tried to make it clear enough so you guys/girls can understand it. If I am missing something or doing something wrong please let me know! Its my first question.

**What I want:**

I want it to show the `voornaam` out of the table `Klanten` to show next to the other ones out of the table `onderwerpen`. For example I want the `voornaam` to show next to the `henk` and `koken`. So I expect it to show the data out 2 different tablesin the block you can see on the pic.

I tried using a foreach loop with 2 conditions but that it not possible. So I was wondering what the solution in this case needs to be. Because It works with 1 condition in the `foreach` but it is not possible to do this with 2 conditions.

**What I have tried:**

```
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Onderwerpen</h3>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->          

    <div class="box-body">
<?php
     $onderrwerp = $app->get_onderwerpen();
     $klantten = $app->get_klanten();
     foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp and $klantten as $klant){
       echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
       echo '<a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie">' . $onderwerp['voornaam'].'</a>';
       echo '<h3>'.$onderwerp['naam'].'</h3><br>'; 
       echo '<a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie">'  .$onderwerp['naam'].'</a>';
       echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

**The code:**

```
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Onderwerpen</h3>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->                 
<div class="box-body">
<?php
 $onderrwerp = $app->get_onderwerpen();
 foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp){
   echo '<div class="well well-sm">';
   echo '<h3>'.$onderwerp['naam'].'</h3><br>'; 
   echo '<a href="https://tom.lbmedia.nl/reactie">'  .$onderwerp['naam'].'</a>';
   echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

[image: How it looks like with this code]

[image: Database 1.]

[image: Database 2.]

**The functions:**

```
public function get_onderwerpen(){
        $getOnderwerp = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM onderwerpen ORDER BY id ASC");
        $onderwerpen = $this->database->resultset();

        return $onderwerpen;

   }
public function get_klanten(){
        $getKlant = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM klanten ORDER BY punten DESC");
        $klanten = $this->database->resultset();

        return $klanten;

    }
```

Comment: `foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp and $klantten as $klant)` is not [valid PHP code](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: your question is not clear .. 1) you ask about database but could be you mean table? .. 2) add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @feeela Yes I know that now but how do I fix it than?

Comment: You may fetch the data as requried using [SQL JOIN's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) instead of fetching each table on its own and then try to fumble around with the data in PHP code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of the tables, and expected output. Also, best not to put images of output, show as text.

Comment: @Hille There is code with what I have tried and there is code what I use for the pic, What I expect is it to show data from 2 different databases there. It needs too show info out nof the `klanten` database and the `onderwerp` db

Comment: @SloanThrasher eddited it

Comment: @helpmeiamagodornot please specify your problem. You said what you want, but not where you stuck at.

Comment: @Hille as you can see with what I have tried you cant use `foreach($onderrwerp as $onderwerp and $klantten as $klant)` this code so I am asking for a way to get it to show anyway

Comment: @helpmeiamagodornot as far as I can see: You said nothing about the `foreach` in your question. Most of the users will read the question and if the question does not include the problem, then they don't read the comments. I just wanna help :)

Comment: Just add another `foreach` to output the other db values.. I still dont understand *next to the other ones*? Do you mean in the same box, **2** box's or in columns, please explain in detail. Your image is showing the contents of `Database 2` but your saying that's what you want :/

Comment: I asked you to edit your question and show the schema of the tables, not just sample data. Also, I said not to post images. Really hard to copy paste text from images to try and craft a response.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two tables. they are connected using the ledenpagina_id field I assume looking at your data. 
What you are looking for is to JOIN the two tables so that with one query you can fetch the data you want and then do a loop to show the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM klanten JOIN onderwerpen
ON klanten.lendenpagina_id = onderwerpen.lendenpagina_id
```

You can then add WHERE clause, ORDER_BY and so on.